# swf working in Chrome but the spacing of the layer is off?

Tags: google-chrome, flash, spacing

Here's the problem:
My sister has a website (www.marycookma.com) and it was created using DreamWeaver with layers.    I've recently added an swf using Dreamweaver.  It will play in Chrome and IE but the layer for the swf is in a different position in Chrome than it is in IE.  The spacing is correct in IE.

It is the only page that has this problem.  I have tried different code suggestions for adding the swf however the code I am currently using allows the movie to appear and run correctly.

My problem is the spacing around the layer.  I don't know why it's any different than other layers except that it has swf code inside it.

Can anyone please point me to the problem?  I inherited the website and I am trying to help keep it going but I'm not up to speed on a lot of things.

I tried to post the two images (viewed through Chrome and viewed through IE) but I'm a newbie so it wouldn't let me. :-(

Here is the code I'm using for the swf video:

```
<div id="Layer22">
```

```
<param name="movie" value="FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf" />
<param name="salign" value="lt" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="scale" value="noscale" />
<param name="FlashVars" value="&MM_ComponentVersion=1&skinName=Clear_Skin_3&streamName=TV2012&autoPlay=false&autoRewind=false" />
<embed src="FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf" flashvars="&MM_ComponentVersion=1&skinName=Clear_Skin_3&streamName=TV2012&autoPlay=false&autoRewind=false" quality="high" scale="noscale" width="390" height="400" name="FLVPlayer" salign="LT" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"/>
```

I hope I have included everything that you need.  Please let me know if you can tell what the issue it.  I very much appreciate the help.

Thank you,
Nancy

Comment: Can you be more specific about what's wrong with the spacing and also provide a link to the page on your site ?

Comment: @Tommy,
The layer where I have the swf is about an inch or more further down on the page than it should be.  It also overlaps another layer below is as well but when I look in Dreamweaver, none of the layers overlap and when it's viewed in IE, it looks ok.  

Here is the link directly to that page:
http://www.marycookma.com/audiovis.htm

Note that I have not uploaded the small line of text in the layer that goes directly beneath the first video.

I uploaded a copy of the page I'm working on to the server where you can see the difference. Go to http://www.marycookma.com/audiovis1.htm.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at the page, as for the positioning of your divs/layers they are controlled by the styles for example:

> div id="Layer22"

(your player) positioning is controlled by this style:

```
#Layer22 {
position:absolute;
width:397px;
height:312px;
z-index:26;
left: 289px;
top: 263px;
}
```

More specifically the top attribute (263px), adjusting top you move the divs/layers up or down. This is true for all Layers in your page.

As for Layer22 with the player if you compare it to the next player in Layer17 there is an iframe in the Layer17 div, if Layer17 behaves maybe you should copy that iframe and use in Layer22.

Hope this helps you some.

Comment: Hi @Tommy -
I don't see an iframe in Layer17 but I see one in Layer19?  Can you give me an example of where (within the code) I can place the iframe info? In Layer22, it has object code with parameters so I'm unclear where and what to insert.

Thanks for all your help Tommy.

Comment: I have the spacing figured out.  I adjusted the "top" setting. Now I'm having trouble with an audio file that I need to add.  It's another mp3 so I created a layer then pasted in the audio code (from another one) but when I save it and preview it, it won't play.  Any ideas?

*code*
<div id="Layer29">
 <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="400" height="27" src="http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3523697345-audio-player.swf" flashvars="audioUrl=http://www.marycookma.com/info/raskin.mp3" quality="best"></embed>

Can you see what's wrong?
Thank you,

Comment: Seems like the audioUrl is wrong ? http://www.marycookma.com/info/raskin.mp3 and possibly the src http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3523697345-audio-player.swf I cannot reach any of these.